# Saved object array not showing up in new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Every time my add button is pressed I am attempting to append that specific item into an array of Item. It prints in the console for each new cell, however when I push to a new ViewController, which will be a summary of all the items added, it does not print the items. Only an empty array is printed.

```
     class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, PostCellDelegate {
      var finalList = [Item]()

@objc func addTapped(cell: PostCell) {

      guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)  else {return}
      hiddenRows.insert(indexPath.row)
      cell.removeButton.isHidden = false
      let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
      finalList.append(item)
       }

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

            cell.delegate = self

     let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
     cell.set(name: item.name, brand: item.brand, price: item.price)
     print(finalList)
     return cell
   }
  @objc private func handleNext() {
       let nextIndex = min(pageControl.currentPage + 1, itemsArr.count - 1)
       let indexPath = IndexPath(item: nextIndex, section: 0)
    if pageControl.currentPage == 4{

        let checkoutView = FinishViewController()
               self.navigationController?.pushViewController(checkoutView, animated: true)
               checkoutView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
               present(checkoutView, animated: true)
        print("last item")
    }else {
        print("not last")
    }
       pageControl.currentPage = nextIndex
       collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
   }

   lazy var pageControl: UIPageControl = {
       let pc = UIPageControl()
       pc.currentPage = 0
       pc.numberOfPages = 4
       pc.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .red
       pc.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 207/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1)
       return pc
   }()

 class FinishViewController: UIViewController {


let cV = CollectionViewController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    print(cV.finalList)
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .red 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in the `FinishViewController` you are initializing a new instance of `CollectionViewController`, so the property has the default empty array value.

You need to pass in the array to the `FinishViewController` when you present or segue to it.

In `FinishViewController` add the following:

```
var finalList = [Item]()
```

And in `handleNext` make sure you set `finalList` correctly:

```
let checkoutView = FinishViewController()
checkoutView.finalList = self.finalList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @objc func addTapped(cell: PostCell) {

      guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)  else 
        {return}
      hiddenRows.insert(indexPath.row)
      cell.removeButton.isHidden = false
      let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
      finalList.append(item)
      collectionView?.reloadData()    <---- add this
 }
```

Comment: I added the line however it still prints an empty array once the new view is presented.